# filter values in column with a loop?

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I am trying to program a simple loop to run through the user selected values and filter out some number display and the numbers I want in a different column.
I have 10 random numbers in a column in this order:

```
3
7
10
12
5
2
7
13
9
23
```

I essentially want to ignore the first value, retrieve the next two values, skip the fourth 
value, retrieve the next two values and so on. So my output would be:

```
7
10
5
2
13
9
```

All I have is a loop that runs through the column. I think I would have to use the mod() function but I can't sem to get it right. All I have so far is this empty loop:

```
Sub findValues()

Do While Cells(x, 3).Value <> "" 'go through values in column 3 until empty cell is encountered
    'skip first value
    'retrieve next two values and put them in different column
    '...
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I've added a formula solution to my VBA solution in case that is of more use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution to do it using a loop and Step 3.

It's not the fastest or optimized way, but it's one of many methods that works and this method is rather simplistic. The example assumes that the data is in column A and the new list will be output to column B.

Since you want to skip the first value, I start the loop at A2, then do a Step 3 each loop (but copy over 2 elements, so it'll always skip the 3rd element).

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = 1

For i = 2 To lastRow Step 3
    Cells(j, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Cells(j + 1, 2).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    j = j + 2
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that using *Cells(row, column)* is better for looping than Range() notation (and faster, too).

Comment: thanks for response. I was happy to see this as a simple copy and paste approach which made it simple for me to modify it to my specs and make it work! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

***[Update: formula solution]***

enter this in D1 and copy down 2/3 the length of your C column
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,OFFSET($C$1,INT(ROW()/2)*3+1,0),OFFSET($C$1,INT(ROW()/2)*3-1,0))

**[initial post]**

I've used a variant array as its more efficient (albeit slightly more complex) than a loop

In short what you were looking for is a Mod function where
(Row-1) Mod 3 = 0
should be excluded

ie exclude position 1,4,7 etc

This code dumps the output from column C to D. It will cater for as many values that exist in C (note I have set the c range by looking up from bottom not down from top, so blanks wont through the code out)

```
Sub GetValues()
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim lngCnt As Long
        Dim lngCnt2 As Long
        Dim X
        Dim Y
        Set rng1 = Range([c1], Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        X = rng1
        ReDim Y(1 To 2 / 3 * rng1.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
        For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
            If (lngCnt - 1) Mod 3 <> 0 Then
            lngCnt2 = lngCnt2 + 1
            Y(lngCnt2, 1) = X(lngCnt, 1)
            End If
        Next
        [d1].Resize(UBound(Y, 1), 1) = Y
    End Sub]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. With a nice picture too! The code approach you did first works out for me because I want to use it a macro.